# ORDER BY COUNT with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, `users` and `clients_closed_1`.

I need to order the result by the count of the rows on the table `client_closed_1` where meeting=1.

I did it for `time_closed` field but that was easy because there was no condition.

It's a part of a search code so I'll show you all of it.
With this code I manage to order it by meeting - but users who has no rows with meeting=1 isn't pull out from the database and I need them to show even if they doesn't have meetings.

```
if (project_type($_GET['project']) == 1)    {
    $table = 'clients_closed_1';
}   else    {
    $table = 'clients_closed_2';
}
    $s_query = "SELECT *,COUNT(time_closed) as numc FROM `".$table."` FULL JOIN `users` ON users.ID=user_c WHERE 1=1";
    if (isset($_POST['search']))    {   
        if ($_POST['tm'] == 'da')   {
                $dd = strtotime($_POST['y']."-".$_POST['m']."-".$_POST['d']);
                $s_query = $s_query." && DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed)) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(".$dd."))";
        }   
        elseif ($_POST['tm'] == 'mon')  {
            $s_query = $s_query." && YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed))=".$_POST['y']." && MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed))=".$_POST['m'];
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['search_name']))  {
            $s_query = $s_query." && CONCAT(p_name,' ',l_name) LIKE '%".$_POST['search_name']."%'";
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['level']))    {
            $query = "&& (level=3 && project IN (SELECT `project` FROM `project` WHERE type='2')) || level=4";
        }
    }   else    {
        $s_query = $s_query." && YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed))=YEAR(NOW()) && MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed))=MONTH(NOW())";
    }

if (isset($_GET['order']))  {
    if ($_GET['order'] == 'closing')    {
        $s_query = $s_query." GROUP BY users.ID ORDER BY numc DESC";
    }
    elseif ($_GET['order'] == 'meeting')    {
        $s_query = $s_query." && meeting='1' GROUP BY users.ID ORDER BY numd DESC";
    }
}
$query = $db->query($s_query);
```

If you need any more code/doedn't understand something comment please and I'll fix it.

Thank you.

EDIT:
example of `$s_query`:

```
   SELECT *,COUNT(time_closed) as numc, COUNT(meeting) as numd FROM `clients_closed_1`
   FULL JOIN `users` ON users.ID=user_c WHERE 1=1 && 
    YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed))=YEAR(NOW()) && 
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed))=MONTH(NOW()) 
    GROUP BY users.ID ORDER BY numc DESC
```

Comment: Can you post an example of $s_query value?

Comment: Where is `meeting=1` in your posted code?

Comment: @segarci I edited the question with an example. But it's working fine. I just can't order it by count of rows with meeting=1.

Comment: @Reeno Sorry I post the wrong code. I edited the code to the correct one.

Comment: Apparently you restrict the query to the people with a meeting (`meeting='1'`), so why do you expect to get people without a meeting? What happens if you omit the `meeting='1'`?

Comment: @Reeno As I sayed in the qeustion. This is the best I could get to. to order it by the number of rows where `meeting=1`. But I need a way to order it that way and still get the result where meeting isn't 1. Ofcourse I need to omit the `meeting=1`, but when I do It's count every row without considirtion if `meeting=1` or not.

Comment: Is users.id a unique field? If there are multiple rows with the same id then it will have to be handled differently. What if one id contains various "meeting" codes, your GROUP BY users.id would throw that off

Comment: @KirkLogan users.ID is uniuqe. BUT client_closed_1.user_c isn't unique if it's matters.

Comment: Another question, do you actually need it ordered by time_closed as well? or was that just part of your quick fix?

Comment: @KirkLogan I need to let the user decide how he would like to order it. by `time_closed`, `meeting` ot `status` but `status` isn't in the question, it's similar to my `meeting` problem.

Comment: @KirkLogan I found a really good way of doing it. see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure I understand 100% of the criteria youre looking for but here is a rough draft of the query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.meeting, temp1.time_closed_count, temp2.meeting_count, temp3.status_count
FROM `clients_closed_1` c
FULL JOIN `users` u
ON c.user_c=u.ID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT time_closed, count(time_closed) time_closed_count FROM clients_closed_1 GROUP BY time_closed) temp1
ON c.time_closed = temp1.time_closed
LEFT JOIN (SELECT meeting, count(meeting) meeting_count FROM clients_closed_1 GROUP BY meeting) temp2
ON c.meeting = temp2.meeting
LEFT JOIN (SELECT status, count(status) status_count FROM clients_closed_1 GROUP BY status) temp3
ON c.status = temp3.status
WHERE 1=1 
AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed))=YEAR(NOW()) 
AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_closed))=MONTH(NOW()) 
ORDER BY {$order_criteria} DESC
```

Whats happeneing here is, we are doing the count of all distinct meeting values in a subquery and joining it to the original query based on the value of "meeting" for each row.

This gives us the total "meetings" grouped by distinct meeting values, without cutting out rows. Such is the same for the other 2 subqueries.

This also cleans things up a bit and allows us to just insert the `$order_criteria`, where that could be time_closed count, meeting_count, or status_count. Just set a default (id) in case your user does not choose anything :)

Edit: Id also recommend trying to get out of the `SELECT *` habit. Specify the columns you need and your output will be much nicer. Its also far more efficient when you start dealing with larger tables.

Comment: First, thank you! But when i give the name `c` to the table `clients_closed_1` mysql is returning an error. I tried to do it without giving it name, but then if i change line 6 in the query to `clients_closed_1.time_closed=temp1.time_closed` mysql returning an error that this column doesn't exist. any suggestions? thank you again.

Comment: time_closed is on the clients_closed_1 table correct?

Comment: update: I tried it with LEFT JOIN instead of FULL JOIN and it worked, but It didn't order it correctly and as I know it would gave me duplicate results

Comment: Add a GROUP BY clause to filter duplicate id's (I wasnt sure if you needed to or not)

Comment: Thank you !! I got it to work. If you want I'll post my query as an answer, there was some changes I had to do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

After I wrote a really long query to do this I found the perfect soulution.

`SELECT SUM(IF(meeting='1' && user_c=users.ID, 1,0)) as meeting_count FROM clients_closed_1 JOIN users`

This query return as `meeting_count` the number of meeting which their value is '1'.

I didn't know I can do such thing until now, so I shared it here. I guess it can be helpull in the future.